# Define Base-URL for img src via CSS

Tags: css

Is it possible to define the base URL used for <img>-tags of a certain class via CSS?

For example my <img>-tag would look like

```
<img class="switchingURL" src="pic1.png">
```

Then I'd like a kind of CSS element like:

```
.switchingURL {base-url: /images/;}
```

Then if I want another picture set, I'd rewrite it to something like:

```
.switchingURL {base-url: http://www.tempsite.de/newstyle/images/;}
```

Does a tag similar to the base-url I used in the examples above exist?

Comment: AFAIK, no, but if you know the image size a'priori you can use `background-image: url(...)` under a generic block element instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEARCH NO MORE , you **can not** do that with css .

but  it's your lucky day , with a simple line of jquery you can do that .

```
$('img[src=""]').attr("src", "images/someimg.jpg")
```

the above line searches for empty src and sets it to `images/someimg.jpg`